# AdaboostClassfier（n_estimstor=1）とbase_modelとで、モデルのscoreが違うのはおかしいでしょうか？原因が分かりません。

Tags: python, scikit-learn

sklearnのAdaboostClassfierを試していたのですが、以下のような疑問にぶつかりました。

n_estimator=1したときのAdaboostのscoreと、base_modelのscoreは全く同じだと思い、実行したところ、scoreに差があった。この原因は何か？

使用したデータは行数200、列数7のデータで、それぞれに「1」「2」「3」「4」いずれかのラベルがついています。また、ラベルの種類1つごとに、そのラベルのデータが50ずつ存在し、ラベルの種類によってデータ数に偏りはありません。

稚拙な文章で分かりずらかったら申し訳ございません。

以下コードです。

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(
    x,  # 行数200列数7のデータ
    y,  # ラベル（1～4のいずれか）
    stratify=y,
    test_size=0.2,
    random_state=0
)

base_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(
    random_state=0,
    max_depth=2
    )

base_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(base_model.score(x_train,y_train))
print(base_model.score(x_test,y_test))
-->0.99375
-->1.0

model_Ada1 = AdaBoostClassifier(
    n_estimators=1,
    random_state=0,
    base_estimator=base_model
    )

model_Ada1.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(model_Ada1.score(x_train,y_train))
print(model_Ada1.score(x_test,y_test))
--> 0.75
--> 0.75
```